# Getting Record values from Neo4j Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I have got some query results from Neo4j in the form of Array[AnyRef]. Each array element looks like this:

```
Record<{group_name: "Amig@s & Friends", event_name: "Dia de Los muertos   Day of the dead", venue_name: "Dvorak Park (Pilsen)", distance: 2615.3793888968457}>
```

The question is how can I extract group_name, event_name, venue_name and distance as fields in order to write them to csv file or create a dataframe in Spark? Is there some method for extracting records values?

Here is my code for querying logic:

```
  def execNeo4jSearchQuery(neo4jSession: Session, data: Array[String]) = {
   val query1 = "MATCH (m:Member)-[mtg_r:MT_TO_MEMBER]->(mt:MemberTopics)-[mtt_r:MT_TO_TOPIC]->(t:Topic), (t1:Topic)-[tt_r:GT_TO_TOPIC]->(gt:GroupTopics)-[tg_r:GT_TO_GROUP]->(g:Group)-[h_r:HAS]->(e:Event)-[a_r:AT]->(v:Venue) WHERE mt.topic_id = gt.topic_id AND distance(point({ longitude: " + data(2) +  ", latitude: " + data(1) + "}),point({ longitude: v.lon, latitude: v.lat })) < 4000 AND mt.member_id = " + data(0) + " RETURN distinct g.group_name " +
      "as group_name, e.event_name as event_name, v.venue_name as venue_name, distance(point({ longitude: " + data(2) +  ", latitude: " + data(1) + "}),point({ longitude: v.lon, latitude: v.lat })) as distance"

    val results = neo4jSession.run(query1).list()
    val resultsArray = results
       .toArray()
       .map(_.toString)
       .foreach(println)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Session.run`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/StatementRunner.html) returns a `StatementResult` allowing to iterate on [`Record`](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/Record.html) entries, so they can be transformed as you wish. So here are a few examples.

To write into a CSV file:

```
// the fields to retrieve
val fieldsToRetrieve = Seq("group_name", "event_name", "venue_name")

// shortcut to produce a line in the CSV
def recordToCsv(rec: Record): String =
  fieldsToRetrieve.map(rec.get(_).asString()).mkString(",")

// execute the query and write into CSV
val queryResult = neo4jSession.run("[query]")

val writer = new PrintWriter("myFile.csv")
while(queryResult.hasNext) {
  val csvLine = recordToCsv(queryResult.next)
  writer.println(csvLine)
}
// don't forget to close the writer
```

To create a Spark DataFrame:

```
private val session: SparkSession = ...

import session.implicits._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ // necessary to convert Neo4j's list of Records

// the fields to retrieve
val fieldsToRetrieve = Seq("group_name", "event_name", "venue_name")

// shortcut to produce a sequence of values representing a row in a dataframe
def toRow(record: Record): Seq[String] =
  fieldsToRetrieve.map(record.get(_).asString())

// execute the query and push the results into a Spark dataframe
val df = neo4jSession.run("[query]").list().asScala
                     .map(toRow).toDF()
```

Comment: There is an additional complexity for the DataFrame creation because I want to the pass the data with Spark Streaming as Array[String] and SparkSession can't be used as it may cause infamous NonSerializable Exception

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I am using a version 2.3.0

Comment: `NotSerializableException` is not particularly related with `SparkSession` nor with `Array[String]` type that you mentioned. It occurs when an object that does not implement `Serializable` is passed to Spark, which needs to share it between nodes. What kind of non serializable objects do you have to pass to Spark in this context?

Comment: I get NotSerializableException when I am trying to use SparkContext in foreach method which is included into forEachRDD method. And I do not know how else I can traverse stream values and make dataframes from them

Comment: Do you mean the same `foreach` as in the question (`.foreach(println)`) ? Otherwise could you please post an example?

Comment: Something like this (wordsArrays:DStream[Array[String]]:                                  
       `wordsArrays.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(
      data => {
         val df = neo.cypher(query1).params(Map("lat" -> data(1).toDouble, "lon" -> data(2).toDouble, "id" -> data(0).toInt))
.loadDataFrame
      }
    ))`

Comment: It's very likely to be caused by `neo` ref passed into `foreach`. What is the exact type of this ref? (it does not seem to be an instance of neo4j `Session`)

Comment: = The signature looks like this: `neo:org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j =Neo4j(sparkContext)`

Comment: Indeed, this must be related with `neo` ref. `Neo4j` is not `Serializable`. There should be a way to avoid the inclusion. Is the `DStream` instance a "must use" or you can face other approaches?

Comment: Unfortunately, DStream is must use. But I thought of another way by simply using a connection to the Neo4j Driver